# Discord.py-Rewrite Taking a list of blacklisted terms and checks if arguments after command contains one of the blacklisted terms

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

### MY GOAL

I am working on a discord bot similar to "Discord Delivers" and "Pizza Byte". And I am trying to take a list of terms/keywords and check if the arguments after the command (The code for the command is at the end of this post); So if they do `>order BadWord` then it checks if it contains one of the previously specified blacklisted terms, and if so, does like `await ctx.send("Due to your order containing one of the blacklisted terms, your order will not be placed.")` Or something like that. I am sorry for not saying what i have tried, as all i can think of, is doing things like `if args in blacklist:` or something like that for each word.

### MY CODE

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def order(ctx, *, orderItem):
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL ID OF THE CHANNEL)
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
    global baseNumberID
    baseNumberID += 1
    global orderIDdf
    global df
    df[str(baseNumberID)] = ctx.author.name
    embed=discord.Embed(title="New order", color=0xfc57ff)
    embed.add_field(name="Who and Where", value="{} in {} in the {} channel".format(ctx.message.author, ctx.message.guild.name, ctx.message.channel.mention), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="What", value="{}".format(orderItem), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Invite", value="{}".format(link), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Order ID", value="Order ID is {}".format(baseNumberID), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Time", value="{} GM time".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())), inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="End of this Order")
    #Second embed that will be used later.
    deliverIDInfo = str(baseNumberID)
    deliverInfoEmbed=discord.Embed(title="Order Info")
    deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Who and Where", value="{} in {} in the {} channel".format(ctx.message.author, ctx.message.guild.name, ctx.message.channel.mention), inline=False)
    deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="What", value="{}".format(orderItem), inline=False)
    deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Invite", value="{}".format(link), inline=False)
    deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Order ID", value="Order ID is {}".format(baseNumberID), inline=False)
    deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Time", value="{} GMT time".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())), inline=True)
    deliverInfoEmbed.set_footer(text="End of this Order")
    orderIDdf[deliverIDInfo] = deliverInfoEmbed
    await ctx.author.send("Your order has been placed!")
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

### EXTRA

And if possible, could the blacklisted terms be in like either a json file or a text file? Thanks.

### EDIT: CLARIFICATION

I thought i should clarify that I do in fact define the variables that are used. Everything works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Without the `json` library:

```py
blacklist = ['test', 'yolo'] #Your blacklisted words here
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def order(ctx, *, orderItem):
    if orderItem.lower() in blacklist:
        await ctx.send("Due to your order containing one of the blacklisted terms, your order will not be placed.")
    else:
        #Your code here
```

- Using the `json` library:

The json file (which will contain every blacklisted words)

```
['test', 'yolo']
```

```py
from json import loads

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def order(ctx, *, orderItem):
    with open('blacklist.txt', 'r') as file:
        blacklist = loads(file.read())
    if orderItem.lower() in blacklist:
        await ctx.send("Due to your order containing one of the blacklisted terms, your order will not be placed.")
    else:
        #Your code here
```