# discord.py-rewrite Trying to blacklist certain terms only works when its only the blacklisted term

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

### My Goal and some Background Info

Hello, About a day ago, I tried to blacklist certain terms so if the user said something inappropriate, then it wont continue with the command (My stackoverflow question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741116/discord-py-rewrite-taking-a-list-of-blacklisted-terms-and-checks-if-arguments-af)) And I tried mixing it with blacklisting certain people, (My stackoverflow question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748231/discord-py-rewrite-blacklist-certain-people-from-using-the-bot)) But the blacklisting of the words only work if its nothing but the blacklisted term. The code command can be found

### My Command's Code

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def order(ctx, *, orderItem):
    with open('blacklist.json', 'r') as file:
            blacklist = loads(file.read())
    with open('user_blacklist.json', 'r') as file:
        user_blacklist = loads(file.read())
    if ctx.author.id in user_blacklist:
        await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from ordering from Discord Chinese")
        return
    else:
        print(orderItem.lower() in blacklist)
        print(orderItem.lower())
        print(blacklist)
        if orderItem.lower() in blacklist:
            await ctx.send("Due to your order containing one of the blacklisted terms, your order will not be placed.")
        else:
            channel = bot.get_channel(724051586728460290)
            link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
            global baseNumberID
            baseNumberID += 1
            global orderIDdf
            global df
            df[str(baseNumberID)] = ctx.author.name
            embed=discord.Embed(title="New order", color=0xfc57ff)
            embed.add_field(name="Who and Where", value="{} in {} in the {} channel".format(ctx.message.author, ctx.message.guild.name, ctx.message.channel.mention), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="What", value="{}".format(orderItem), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Invite", value="{}".format(link), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Order ID", value="Order ID is {}".format(baseNumberID), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Time", value="{} GM time".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())), inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="End of this Order")
            #Second embed that will be used later.
            deliverIDInfo = str(baseNumberID)
            deliverInfoEmbed=discord.Embed(title="Order Info")
            deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Who and Where", value="{} in {} in the {} channel".format(ctx.message.author, ctx.message.guild.name, ctx.message.channel.mention), inline=False)
            deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="What", value="{}".format(orderItem), inline=False)
            deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Invite", value="{}".format(link), inline=False)
            deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Order ID", value="Order ID is {}".format(baseNumberID), inline=False)
            deliverInfoEmbed.add_field(name="Time", value="{} GMT time".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())), inline=True)
            deliverInfoEmbed.set_footer(text="End of this Order")
            orderIDdf[deliverIDInfo] = deliverInfoEmbed
            await ctx.author.send("Your order has been placed!")
            await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

### My Issue

The user blacklisting properly works, but the keywords doesn't. So say the blacklisted term is `Ubisoft` then it works if the args is `Ubisoft`/`ubisoft` But if its `Words words Ubisoft` then it doesn't work, it allows the order to come through.

### My Guess of the Issue

I'm assuming its because when it either checks it, or takes the input, it doesn't check it properly, maybe it saves as an either array or weird form of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem right now is that `string in blacklist` only works if `blacklist` exactly contains `string`. Any variations and it won't work. Instead, you should loop through each blacklisted word and check if the word is in the message, like this:

```
if any(black_word in orderItem.lower() for black_word in blacklist):
    await ctx.send("Due to your order containing one of the blacklisted terms, your order will not be placed.")
    return
```

The `any` function will return `True` if **any** blacklisted words are in `orderItem.lower()`

As an example, if the `blacklist` is `['word1', 'word2']`, and the message is `'word1 extra'`, the original code will not work because the exact string `'word1 extra'` is not in blacklist. But the blacklisted word `'word1'` is in `'word1 extra'`.

Also, after you `return` you don't need to put an else statement. So for the user blacklist it should be:

```
if ctx.author.id in user_blacklist:
    await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from ordering from Discord Chinese")
    return

# rest of code, not in an else block
```

Comment: It seems like, when i try this, the command doesn't work. It doesn't place the order, it doesn't say that im blacklisted or that i used a blacklisted, it doesn't even say an errors in the console. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try placing a print at the beginning to see if the function is called at all.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late! I tried to do the print thing as you said and it didn't print, so I tried a different command it nothing is working other than the cycle for going through different statuses. So I'm assuming the prefix isn't working.

Comment: I tried removing the background task from the "on_ready" part and for some reason, thats whats breaking it. It seems like it waits for the background task to be ready before it starts? Im not sure.

Comment: Your answer works, All i need to do now is figure out why my code to cycle through different statuses causes no commands to work.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would do that. Could you share a link to your code? And make sure when you try a command it is with the prefix the bot is currently using.

Comment: Here you go: https://hastebin.com/nigudawuxi.py 
 And also, It works just fine if i get rid of the `my_background_task`

Comment: Judging from line 5, you want the prefix to be something other than what it's set to. Remember that the background task sets both the game activity and the prefix to the same thing. So if it was on the first one the entire discord command would be `PREFIX: CF>testingBothBlacklist` If you want to set the game activity to `PREFIX: CF>` and the prefix to `CF` you should change the lambda functions to return a tuple of the activity and prefix, and set the values accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to remove that bit of code when i added it. And when you said i don't need to `return` with my user blacklist, i added that because I'm still used to a broken installation of python where i had to put return or else it would run through all of the code without checking.

Comment: So you figured it out? Also, I'm confused, didn't I say that you do need a return, but you don't need an else?

Comment: Sorry, I mean't `else`.Yeah i figured it out. Everything is working now. and another issue i had was i forgot to add the `while True:` loop to the status switching through. After that however, everything worked.